# 403 for an Authenticated user

Tags: strapi, user-permissions

Why **"/api/users/:id"** get 403 for an Authenticated user, even if the "**update**" was selected for such a role?

*I tested the functionality by Postman, and it does not a token problem because when I get a wrong token I receive "Missing or invalid credentials"*

**Strapi Version  4.13.6 (node v18.17.1)**

The goal was to change the user profile info!